# Will Vue follow component or dom hierarchy for keyboard event bindings?

Tags: vuejs3

I've seen that Vue3 has support for 'portals' via the Teleport component, which can render the dom of a component into a different place in the document then the component was specified.

Reading the docs gives the impression that all events, properties etc will follow the Vue component order, but that seems to be in conflict with Javascripts native bubbling of events.

Will keyboard bindings follow Vue component parents, the actual DOM, or somehow both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM events are always DOM events, so they always propagate along the DOM tree, vue cannot change that.

The teleport documentation says that:

> If teleport contains a **Vue component**, it will remain a logical child component of the teleport’s parent

So the special handling only happens when you are teleporting a vue component. The props passing and event emitting hence refer only to components.